# Postgresql join two tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm having issues with join two tables this is my query

```
SELECT
    "tbl_Clientes"."Cedula"
FROM
    "tbl_Clientes" c
JOIN
    "tbl_Observaciones" o ON ("tbl_Clientes"."Id_Clave_Nombre" = "tbl_Observaciones."ID_Cliente")
```

I get this error:

> Syntax error at or near "ID_Cliente"

What am I missing?

Comment: You are missing the closing double quote after `tbl_Observaciones`

Comment: oh sorry :( my bad thank you so much

Comment: Another reason why it’s better to not use uppercase names: you don’t need double quotes and you can’t forget what you don’t need

Comment: you right i got this db from another developer, i will rename all to not use uppercase thanks for the tip

Comment: I think that Frank means to avoid mixed-case. Like with your other SQL question today, mixed case requires double-quotation-marks and these make syntax errors more likely.
`SELECT C.CEDULA FROM CLIENTES C
JOIN OBSERVACIONS O ON (CLIENTES.ID_CLAVE_NOMBRE = OBSERVACIONES.ID_CLIENTE)` would be fine if your naming convention used capitals. `SELECT tbl_clientes.Cedula FROM tbl_clientes c JOIN tbl_observaciones o ON (tbl_clientes.id_clave_nombre = "tbl_observaciones.id_cliente) would be fine too, if you used that naming convention.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting [Jonas Metzler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77334823/postgresql-calculate-age-in-years-based-on-birthdate):

> Remove all these useless quotes ... using quotes and camel case in SQL, as you do, is very bad practise and easily leads to issues (as you see here). In SQL, we use snake case.

The error occurred because a closing quotation mark was missing from the end of the JOIN clause, `"tbl_Observaciones."ID_Cliente"`.

Comment: Please avoid to write such useless answers. Generally, questions with issues caused by typos will be closed and don't need to be answered at all. If you think writing an answer is helpful or even required, it should add any important information and not just consist of a bunch of text that has already been provided as comments. The information a quotation mark is missing was provided by Malcolm hours before this "answer".